# Angularjs pass multiple arguments to directive ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am stuck in a doubt 
I have html :
Here, there are two types of data : post and person. The json for each post has array of persons. I wish to retrieve the rating Value, dataCategory and id (mydata.id/childData.id) from directive to controller :

```
<div ng-repeat="mydata in data" class="ng-scope ng-binding">

   <p class="ng-binding">{{mydata.postdata}}</p> 
   <div star-rating rating-value="rating" data-cat="post" data-id="{{mydata.id}}" ></div>

   <div ng-repeat="childData in mydata.personRelatedData">
          {{childData.personName}}  
          <div star-rating rating-value="rating" data-cat="person" data-id="{{childData .id}}" >
   </div>
</div>
```

I have a Directive :

```
myDirectives.directive('starRating', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      template: '<div> <ul style="margin : 0px">' +
                  '<li ng-repeat="i in getNumber(myNumber)" ng-click="toggle($index)" id=$index readonly="false">' +                   
                  '</li>' +
                '</ul></div>',

      scope: {
        ratingValue: '=',       
        dataCat: '=',  
        dataId: '=',  
        readonly: '@',
        onRatingSelected: '&'       
      },
      link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {       
      scope.myNumber = 5;       
      scope.getNumber = function(num) {
                   return new Array(num);   
        }       

        scope.toggle= function(val) {
               console.log("Val : "+val);
               console.log("dataCat : "+scope.dataCat);
               console.log("dataId : "+scope.dataId);
               ...
        }
```

What should I add in function toggle($index), to pass category name and its id too?
Currently it shows :

```
Val : 1 
dataCat : undefined 
dataId : undefined
```

I am new in angular js and can sense doing something wrong here.. like how to pass scope values to toggle function? Any help would be great..
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

HTML

```
<div star-rating dt-cat="post" dt-id="mydata.id" ></div>
```

In dt-id you shouldn't use **"{{mydata.id}}"**, just use **"mydata.id"**.

JavaScript:

```
myDirectives.directive('starRating', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: '<div ng-click="toggle()">Test</div>',
    scope: {
      dtCat: '@',
      dtId: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.toggle = function() {
        console.log("dtCat: " + scope.dtCat);
        console.log("dtId : " + scope.dtId);
      };
    }
  };
});
```

I test it and I have:

```
dataCat: post
dataId : 5
```

I assumed that **dtCat is string** so you should use **dtCat: '@'**.

I changed **data-** to **dt-** because angular **strip data- from the front of the element/attributes**.

Angular normalizes an element's tag and attribute name to determine which elements match which directives. (...)

The normalization process is as follows:
1. Strip x- and **data-** from the front of the element/attributes.
2. Convert the :, -, or _-delimited name to camelCase.

More: [Creating Custom Directives (section Matching Directives)](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)