# How can I pass an ng-repeated object to my AngularJS directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Take a look at my code here...

Controller ("tasks" is an array of JSON objects resolved in my `Routes.js`):

```
app.controller('testCtrl', function(tasks){
    $scope.tasks = tasks.data;
};
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="client-wrapper">
   <div class="task-wrapper" ng-repeat="taskData in tasks">
     <div task="taskData">
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('task', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {taskData: '=taskData'},
    templateUrl: "/templates/directives/task.html",
    link: function(scope, element, attribute) {
      console.log(scope.taskData);
    }
  };
});
```

For some reason, I seem incapable of figuring out how to pass the current object being looped through in the `tasks` array to this directive so that I can manipulate it therein.

I've tried numerous solutions, as seen below:

[how to pass a json as a string param to a directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14687822/how-to-pass-a-json-as-a-string-param-to-a-directive) <--- which tells me to output `{{ object }}` inside if an HTML attribute, and then `$eval` that back to JSON in the directive...

That's a very gross way of doing it, and I definitely don't want to do it that way (nor do I think this will allow it to two-way-bind back to the actual object in the tasks array in the controllers scope. This method just converts the JSON to string --> evals back to JSON + makes a copy of that string inside the directives scope).

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/angular/RyywTP64sNs/Y_KQLbbwzzIJ <-- Same as above, they're saying to output the JSON as a string in an attribute, and then `$eval` it back to JSON... won't work for me for the same reasons as the first link.

http://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/FHVD9/ <-- Copying his exact syntax isn't possible because the data I want to pass to my directive is *the current index of the tasks array* while being `ng-repeated`... This is close, but doesn't work within the constraints of `ng-repeat` apparently?

[Angularjs pass multiple arguments to directive ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20335509/angularjs-pass-multiple-arguments-to-directive-ng-repeat) <-- This syntax isn't working for me -- if I attempt to pass the `taskData` object (the current representation object in the array being looped through) in a parameter, it passes the literal string "taskData" and not the object itself? At this point I'm really scratching my head.

---

What I'm trying to accomplish (since I might be going about this in the wrong way entirely and feel I should explain the problem as a whole):

I have a bunch of data called `tasks`. They have a few properties, such as:

```
completed: true || false

description: a string

tags: an array of strings
```

Etc, etc.

I am outputting a big table of rows for all of these tasks. Each row will be a directive, *with some buttons you can press **on** that row in order to change the data pertaining to the task on this row*.

I want to have the functions to manipulate the data of each individual task inside the link function of the directive. So like `markAsCompleted()` would be a function within the directive, that would **update the `completed` boolean of whichever task was being clicked on**.

I am doing it this way, because as I see it I have two options:

1. A function in the controller where I pass in the task to modify as a parameter, and then perform the data manipulation
2. **Or** a function in the angular directive that just manipulates the data of the object attached to this particular directive (and my current issue is my apparent inability to two-way bind an object to this particular directive)

I want to be able to accomplish the second option in order to make my directive **modular and stand-alone**.

---

So yeah. I'm confused as to how to go about doing this and would greatly appreciate some insight as to where I'm going wrong :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`scope: {taskData: '=taskData'}` means Angular expects an attribute called `task-data` with the value to be passed in. So give this a try...

```
<div class="client-wrapper">
   <div class="task-wrapper" ng-repeat="taskData in tasks">
     <div task task-data="taskData">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your current attempt your directive is expecting an attribute called `task-data`.

This should fix your problem:

```
app.directive('task', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {task: '='},
    templateUrl: "/templates/directives/task.html",
    link: function(scope, element, attribute) {
      console.log(scope.taskData);
    }
  };
});
```

Notice i changed the name of your property in the directive's scope from `task-data` to `task`